# How does one derive the formula for the parallactic angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, astronomy, geometry

The parallactic angle is defined as that angle between a vector pointing toward the northern celestial pole and a vector pointing toward the northern hemisphere observer's zenith.  I know the formula but how is it derived?